# Android - Integrate React Native View with Native App

Tags: android, react-native

I'm learning React Native, and followed Facebook manual to integrate React Native "Hello World" view into existing native app:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html

I tried to run on device, simulator, Genymotion simulator, but can't pass that annoying red screen of death:

[React Native Blue Sceen of Death](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OUDh.png)

Terminal Log:

```
npm start

reactnativeintegrationdemo@1.0.0 start 
/Users/username/Documents/Demo/ReactNativeIntegrationDemo
node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start

Running packager on port 8081.

Looking for JS files in
/Users/username/Documents/Demo/ReactNativeIntegrationDemo 

[Hot Module Replacement] Server listening on /hot

React packager ready.
11/23/2016, 11:30:53 AM] <START> Initializing Packager
[11/23/2016, 11:30:54 AM] <START> Building in-memory fs for JavaScript
[11/23/2016, 11:30:55 AM] <END>   Building in-memory fs for JavaScript     
(1329ms)
[11/23/2016, 11:30:55 AM] <START> Building Haste Map
[11/23/2016, 11:31:00 AM] <END>   Building Haste Map (4617ms)
[11/23/2016, 11:31:00 AM] <END>   Initializing Packager (6539ms)
[11/23/2016, 11:48:57 AM] <START> Requesting bundle:    
{"url":"/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false"}
[11/23/2016, 11:48:57 AM] <START> Transforming modules
```

Thanks :)

Comment: late reply, but might be useful for others.. that screen comes in only if the react native server is not running with correct version or correct dependencies